# JWT: Why Access & Refresh Token

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt

I'm making an app in Node.js & Mongoose which needs to have some way of authentication. I first thought of simple session but then came across JWT's. I read through many articles but I'm still unsure if I should use them. My questions are:

1. Let's say someone steals a short lived access token that expires in 15 minutes, wouldn't the refresh token be useless, as 15 minutes is a lot of time to do something?
2. Where & How should I store refresh & access tokens? I guess access in client side memory and refresh tokens in database? But what if a attacker hacked the database and got the refresh token? Does he have acccess then?
3. Are there any other secure and good ways of authenticate with Node.js?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 15 minutes is better than "forever". If you loose the token and someone finds it chances are the token is outdated already. If you loose a token that ja valid for a year the risk of it being valid goes up significantly. Both tokens are stored in the client, but scoped differently, e.g. the refresh token only for the actual refresh path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Short lived token is much better than non-expiring or longer life token so absolutely no to longer life. token loss/theft is a problem that needs dual solution to lock the client to server (ip lock is a bad idea given the ip spoofing) the real solution depends on how deep you want to go like going through a third service establishing trust among both. logout is always possible all depends on as soon the server stops recognising its issued token and client app can code the logic and server rejection.
2. storing token to persistent storage is not hacker proof unless there is a some sort of transformation like decryption or unwrapping in the server side application layer before storage (so that the token is not as is on client side as stored in the db.).
3. there are quite few answers present in JWT RFC https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519  so using it is reasonably secure for majority of applications. Remember security always demands double checking and two factors in each step but there is always a judgment call that applies.